# xml using javascript with attribute missing end tag

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to prepare a XML using JavaScript which should look like below.

```
<Service>
<NewInstance ref="External_UCSD_Serverinfo">
    <Std>DiscoveredElement</Std>
    <Virtual/>
    <Key>Key001</Key>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute name="hpom_citype" value="External_UCSD_Serverinfo"/>
    </Attributes>
</NewInstance>
</Service>
```

i have prepared below code.

```
var doc = builder.newDocument();
var rootElement = doc.createElement("Service");

var NewInstance_node = doc.createElement("NewInstance");
var attr = doc.createAttribute("ref");
attr.setValue("External_UCSD_Serverinfo");
NewInstance_node.setAttributeNode(attr);
rootElement.appendChild(NewInstance_node);


var Std_node = doc.createElement("Std");
Std_node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("DiscoveredElement"));
rootElement.appendChild(Std_node);

    var Std_Virtual = doc.createElement("Virtual");
rootElement.appendChild(Std_Virtual);


var Key_node = doc.createElement("Key");
Key_node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Key001"));
rootElement.appendChild(Key_node);


var CIAttributes_node = doc.createElement("Attributes");
var CIAttribute_node1 = doc.createElement("Attribute");
var attr_name1 = doc.createAttribute("name");
attr_name1.setValue("hpom_citype");
var attr_val1 = doc.createAttribute("value");
attr_val1.setValue("External_UCSD_Serverinfo");
CIAttribute_node1.setAttributeNode(attr_name1);
CIAttribute_node1.setAttributeNode(attr_val1);  
rootElement.appendChild(CIAttributes_node); 
CIAttributes_node.appendChild(CIAttribute_node1);


doc.appendChild(rootElement);

var tf = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
var t = tf.newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
var sw = new StringWriter();
t.transform(new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc), new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw));
```

but as a result i get below Output.

```
   <Service>
   <NewInstance ref='External_UCSD_Serverinfo'/>
      <Std>DiscoveredElement</Std>
      <Virtual/>
      <Key>Key001</Key>
      <Attributes>
         <Attribute name='hpom_citype' value='External_UCSD_Serverinfo'/>
   </Attributes>
   </Service>
```

So i am getting what i am looking for except the end tag of "NewInstance". can soomeone tell me what i am missing? also is there simple way of writing XML Content using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that the nodes Std, Virtual, Key etc. are appended to rootElement instead of NewInstance_node

in detail:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null);
var rootElement = doc.createElement("Service");

var NewInstance_node = doc.createElement("NewInstance");
var attr = doc.createAttribute("ref");
attr.value="External_UCSD_Serverinfo";
NewInstance_node.setAttributeNode(attr);
rootElement.appendChild(NewInstance_node);

var Std_node = doc.createElement("Std");
Std_node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("DiscoveredElement"));
NewInstance_node.appendChild(Std_node);

var Std_Virtual = doc.createElement("Virtual");
NewInstance_node.appendChild(Std_Virtual);

var Key_node = doc.createElement("Key");
Key_node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Key001"));
NewInstance_node.appendChild(Key_node);

var CIAttributes_node = doc.createElement("Attributes");
var CIAttribute_node1 = doc.createElement("Attribute");
var attr_name1 = doc.createAttribute("name");
attr_name1.value="hpom_citype";
var attr_val1 = doc.createAttribute("value");
attr_val1.value="External_UCSD_Serverinfo";
CIAttribute_node1.setAttributeNode(attr_name1);
CIAttribute_node1.setAttributeNode(attr_val1);  
rootElement.appendChild(CIAttributes_node); 
CIAttributes_node.appendChild(CIAttribute_node1);

doc.appendChild(rootElement);
```